# jquery Grid with pagination , sorting and searching

Tags: jquery, grid, pagination, populate

How do I populate 2 jquery grid with pagination, sorting and searching in a single page

Answer (score 4):

Have you bothered to look at the [demos](http://trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)? The demo page is extremely comprehensive and does exactly what you're asking for.